# Adding if-else statement causes JavaScript to stop working

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have an assignment for my web design class & we were given a basic code that we need to modify to do more. As soon as I add an if, else if statement, the javascript stops working. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. If someone could steer me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.
Here's the original code (with notes one what we need to do):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Finish the logic of the Rock Paper Scissors game below. 
     See the comments for instructions. -->
<html>
    <head>
    <title>RPS</title>
    <script>
    function rps() {
        userChoice = prompt("Rock, paper or scissors?");
        userPick.innerHTML = userChoice;
        computerChoice = Math.random();
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
            computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        }
        computerPick.innerHTML = computerChoice;
        result = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
        if (result == 1) {
            // set the outcome entity to say that "Player Wins!"
            // also increment the user's score.
        } else if (result == -1) {
            // set the outcome entity to say that "Computer Wins!"
            // also increment the computer's score.
        } else {
            // set the outcome entity to say "Tie"
        }
    }

    function compare(choice1, choice2) {
        // return 0 if choices are equal,
        // 1 if choice1 wins,
        // -1 if choice2 wins
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>RockPaperScissors</h2>
        <p id="outcome">-</p>   <b> computer picks: </b>
        <p id="computerPick">-</p>  <b> player picks: </b>
        <p id="userPick">-</p>
        <!-- create p blocks to store the computer's score (number of wins)
        and the user's score. These will have to be modified by the rps function
        -->
        <button type="button" onclick="rps()">Go</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is how I changed the function compare method:

```
function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    // return 0 if choices are equal,
    // 1 if choice1 wins,
    // -1 if choice2 wins

    if (choice1 == "paper" && choice2 == "rock" || 
        choice1 == "rock" && choice2 == "scissors" || 
        choice1 == "scissors" && choice2 == "paper") {
        return == 1;
    }
    else if (choice1 == "paper" && choice2 == "scissors" || 
             choice1 == "rock" && choice2 == "paper" || 
             choice1 == "scissors" && choice2 == "rock") {
        return == -1;
    }
    else {
        return == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Samuel Liew: please read the homework tag wiki. Don't add it to new questions.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the == from your returns. They should just be like...

return 1;

== is used for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `compare` function to

```
function compare(choice1, choice2) {
            // return 0 if choices are equal,
            // 1 if choice1 wins,
            // -1 if choice2 wins

            if (choice1=="paper" && choice2=="rock"||choice1=="rock"
&& choice2=="scissors"||choice1=="scissors" && choice2=="paper"){
                return 1;}
            else if (choice1=="paper" &&
choice2=="scissors"||choice1=="rock" && choice2=="paper"||choice1=="scissors" &&
choice2=="rock"){
                return -1;}
            else {
                return 0;}
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
           return 1
```

not

```
           return == 1
```

Return is a keyword not a variable.  = is the assignment operator, which puts the value on the right side of the operator into the variable on the left side. And == is the equality operator.

Comment: `==` is the equality operator.

Comment: I think the OP would feel at home with Pascal.